# Dynamically background colour change in Android studio

Tags: java, android, background

My question is how an application like YouTube music and Spotify change the colour of the background with respect to the poster of any song.

I am giving an example how what it looks like and if anyone can help me to achieve this then please help me.

[image]

If anyone can give me a java code example for this then it will help me a lot. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

use this library from google, click [Here](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/palette/graphics/Palette) to read more about it

```
implementation 'androidx.palette:palette:1.0.0'
```

Example of usage

```
Palette.from(bitmap).generate(palette -> {
    //There is alot of methods you can use whatever wherever you want
    int rgb = palette.getMutedSwatch().getRgb();
    int vibrant = palette.getVibrantSwatch().getRgb();
    int vibrantDark = palette.getDarkVibrantSwatch().getRgb();
    int vibrantLight = palette.getLightVibrantSwatch().getRgb();
    int muted = palette.getMutedSwatch().getRgb();
    int mutedDark = palette.getDarkMutedSwatch().getRgb();
    int mutedLight = palette.getLightMutedSwatch().getRgb()
});
```

and this method is useful if you want hex color

```
private String rgbToHex(int rgb) {
    return String.format("%06x", 0xFFFFFF & rgb);
}
```